# UnitOfWork vs Database connection

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, unit-of-work

I currently have made a UnitOfWork implementation which wraps both the database connection and the transaction.

```
using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
    // do db operations here through repositories

   uow.SaveChanges();
}
```

Rollback will be called if `SaveChanges` haven't been called before the uow gets disposed.

Is it a bad design choice to let the uow handle both the connection and the transaction?

Let's say that I got a ASP.Net MVC website where most of the actions are just fetching information from the database. Are there a performance penalty for creating/committing transactions that aren't actually not doing anything in the database?

Comment: Did you find out whether there's any problem with always creating a transaction, even for just `SELECT` statements?  I'm new to back-end programming and this is what I read in a SQL  book _"Executing a `SELECT` statement within a transaction can create locks on the referenced tables, which can in turn block other users or sessions from performing work or reading data"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to implement UoW then `SaveChanges` should be the only place where a connection and a transaction will be used. UoW will just collect all commands that must be executed and execute them in a transaction when `SaveChanges` is invoked.

Comment: What about the transaction that is always started? I'm new to back-end programming and this is what I read in a SQL  book _"Executing a `SELECT` statement within a transaction can create locks on the referenced tables, which can in turn block other users or sessions from performing work or reading data"_

Answer (score 0):

UoW is domain specific.  I had more-or-less the same implementation you use until someone pointed this out since database access should not *really* influence your domain.

So I ended up splitting the responsibilities.  Since my UoW does make use of repositories that require a connection to a database I still require a connection.

So for instances where I do not require a UoW I will have this:

`using (DatabaseConnectionFactory.Create()) { ... }`

For transaction:

```
using (var connection = DatabaseConnectionFactory.Create().BeginTransaction()) 
{
    // do stuff

    connection.CommitTransaction();
}
```

If I require a UoW (typically *with* transaction):

```
using (var connection = DatabaseConnectionFactory.Create().BeginTransaction())
using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
    // do stuff

    connection.CommitTransaction();
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the Unit of Work yourself (I'm assuming you did). Look into using ADO.NET EF with the Repository pattern.

There is a big camp that feels any database operation should be wrapped in a transaction. You should for sure wrap any Inserts / Updates / Deletes in a transaction.

That being said, wrap any of the database objects that implement IDisposable in a Using Block.